# Replace the text of a specific cell given certain circumstances

Tags: replace, google-sheets, vlookup, google-query-language

I am creating a work schedule for the company I work at. There are four different jobs at the company and therefore 4 separate tabs for schedules.

I have a tab specifically for when an employee calls out sick or requests time off. I am looking for a way for when the user enters the employee's name, specific date, and sick/request off, for it to automatically update the work schedule that that employee belongs too (**Job1**, **Job2**, **Job3**, or **Job4**)

Example:
This is **John Doe**'s Work Schedule for Job 1(and therefore located on **Job1** tab)

[image]

**John Doe** calls out sick on Friday, 01/18/19. The supervisor fills out the following on **Time Off Reqs/Sick** tab

[image]

Given that the user inputs the above data in **Time Off Reqs/Sick** tab, I would like **John Doe**'s Schedule to change automatically in **Job1** tab to the following 
John Doe
[image]

Here is the [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V1G5mjFXZkzo4HQdFmngi6xQBgvVDsZi3ibqhWQCPjQ/edit?usp=sharing) to my dummy data
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: HI. FWIW, I think you have it back-to-front. I'd be doing all my data entry on a single sheet - the "Job" sheets. I'd make each cell a dropdown with the option for "Work", "Sick", or "Off" (or whatever). Then add some code for when "Sick" is selected and update the data on the "Time Off/Req Lists" accordingly.

Comment: Ah, I see! thats clever thinking! I already have the drop down so It shouldn't bee too difficult to change around. Thank you!

Comment: Column C is awash with formulae (350 per sheet). Why not copy the date from Column B into Column C, then format C as Date/Day. The result is right aligned (easily fixed to left align) and in Sentence case rather than Upper (but does that _really_ matter?). That would be 1,200 formula gone in an instant.

Comment: How many jobs do you have running at one time? How many staff on your payroll? Can staff work on multiple jobs in the course of a month? What do you actually use the job sheets for, recording work “after the fact”, as a roster, for payroll, etc? I’m wondering why have multiple sheets? Why not have just one sheet and capture the date, job, name, and work type? Makes it so easy then to analyse data because everything is highly structured and you can QUERY , FILTER, Query AND Filter, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get what you were looking for. See the sheet (and make a copy to modify) [HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ij7XDgiUNY_OgSPLebXPbaJiqx_4jHwzhRWYepPYBOA/edit?usp=sharing).

I used the formula below in each cell of the "Job1" sheet (for this example, I only did it for Column F).

`=IFERROR(IF(AND(D2<>"SATURDAY",D2<>"SUNDAY",ISNA(QUERY(Requests!A$2:C,"Select C where A='"&$F$1&"' and B = date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE(C2),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0)))=TRUE,"Work",QUERY(Requests!A$2:C,"Select C where A='"&$F$1&"' and B = date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE(C2),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0)),"Off")`

You could probably also use multiple `INDEX/MATCH` statements to get what you're looking for. If you restructure the data, you may be able to use `ARRAYFORMULA` to reduce the number of formulas you need to use.

Comment: How would I tweak your formula given that days off can change? It seems like you hard coded days off as Saturday and Sunday.

Comment: You could consider a helper column where you put something in the cell beside the date which indicates it should be an off day. Then change the `IF` statement to something like `=IF(yourcell="yourvalue","Off",IF(ISNA(QUERY(Requests!A$2:C,"Select C where A='"&H$1&"' and B = date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE(C2),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0))=TRUE,"Work",QUERY(Requests!A$2:C,"Select C where A='"&H$1&"' and B = date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE(C2),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0)))` You could also consider changing your data to manually enter requests and work days in one sheet, then extract the jobs/requests from there using `QUERY`